# No aparece opcion Añadir politica de privacidad en Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

Al añadir una nueva aplicación en el apartado:
"Contenido y audiencia objetivo"
me aparece :

> "Debes añadir una política de privacidad si tu audiencia objetivo
> incluye menores de 13 años".

No encuentro la opción de añadir política por ningún sitio. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes realizar para cubrir esta política es lo que indica el documento de Google que es llenar el [cuestionario de clasificación del contenido](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859655).

Abre Play Console y ve a la página Contenido de la app (`Política` > `Contenido de la app` o `Policy` > `App content`).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o simplemente  puedes acceder a esta url:

https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/app/app-content/summary

escoge tu aplicación y responde el cuestionario para que se aplique una audiencia objetivo, es importante que sepas que se calculará automáticamente a partir de las preguntas que respondas sobre tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vale gracias! Estoy pensando poner esta como politica de privacidad. https://gurzelai.github.io/. Mi pregunta es si me van a dejar subirla ya que es una politica bastante mala. Tambien decir que no la añado en la app.

La razon por la que añado la politica es porque es necesario si es para menores de 13 años.

Comment: ya veo tu página pero aunque diga ahí lo ideal es contestar el cuestionario, ya que de otra forma si detecta que cambiaste algo en la app o algo que respondiste no es verdad te pueden eliminar la app :-|