# Donde poner POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD en Play Console

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me han rechazado una app porque según me han dicho no cumple la Potica de Familias y no he puesto el Url de la política en donde hay que ponerlo.

[image: Según pone en el correo debo de meter el url de la política en la ficha de mi app, ¿es aquí?]

[image: Correo notificación de razones de rechazo de app]

[image: Aquí sin embargo si que he añadido mi política de seguridad]

Mi pregunta es, debo de poner el link de la política de seguridad en algún sitio más? Por ahora solo lo tengo en un sitio, dentro de Contenido de la aplicación, en Política de Privacidad. También en la descripción completa? He visto que otras apps no lo tienen.

Comment: Ya realizaste el cuestionario que te sugerí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434385/no-aparece-opcion-a%c3%b1adir-politica-de-privacidad-en-google-play-console ?

Comment: Si claro, fue lo primero que hice

Comment: Puedes escribir tu propia política de privacidad (en la web hay varios ejemplos) y publicarla en tu sitio web (si tuvieras uno), o en Google Sites, en Github u otros que te permiten publicar contenido gratuitamente, poniendo luego esa URL en la ficha de Play Store. Para más detalles consulta [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38252967/5587982). Ahora mismo no recuerdo, pero creo que también debes ponerla en la aplicación, por ejemplo, en las opciones del menú principal si la misma tuviera uno.

Answer (score 1):

También tenía ese problema cuando intentaba registrar mi aplicación pero lo solucioné poniendo un pdf del gobierno que habla sobre las políticas de la privacidad de datos, creo que ahí no hay que colocar un link de una página, creo que es poner un pdf que se encuentre en un dominio, a continuación te dejo el link que usé para desplegar mi app

```
https://www.mintic.gov.co/portal/604/articles-62124_politica_seguridad_privacidad_informacion_resolucion_2256_2020.pdf
```

espero que te ayude, saludos

Comment: Un pdf del gobierno no puede ser una política de privacidad de tu app, tuviste suerte en que tal vez no se revisara, esto no es correcto.  Recuerda que siempre debes agregar la información más importante de los enlaces . revisa [answer], saludos.